# Master theorem for $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^{2}\log n$

Tags: recurrence-relation, master-theorem

Would I use the third case of the [Master Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem) for the recurrence equation $T(n) = 2T(n/2) + n^{2}\log n$?

The condition given for the third case by Wikipedia is $f(n) = \Theta(n^c)$ when $c > \log_{b}a$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes and no. The form of the Master Theorem given on Wikipedia is a bit more restrictive than a fuller version of the theorem, essentially limiting itself to the cases where $f(n)$ is a polynomial.

In this case, where $f(n) \notin \Theta(n^{c})$ for any $c$ (though we do have $f(n) \in \Omega(n^{2})$ and $f(n) \in O(n^{2+\varepsilon})$ for any $\varepsilon > 0$), the condition given on Wikipedia is insufficient.

A more useful (but slightly mathematically harder to work with, sometimes) formulation can be found in Cormen et al.'s "Introduction to Algorithms", or in this [convenient worksheet from MIT](http://people.csail.mit.edu/thies/6.046-web/master.pdf).

The third case in this version is now

> If
>   $$
> f(n) \in \Omega(n^{\log_{b}(a)+\varepsilon}) \text{ with } \varepsilon > 0
> $$
>   where $f(n)$ also has to satisfy a "regularity condition":
>   $$
> a f(\frac{n}{b}) \leq cf(n) \text{ for some } c>1 \text{ and } n \text{ large enough}
> $$
>   then
>   $$
> T(n) \in \Theta(f(n))
> $$

For the recurrence $T(n) = 2T(\frac{n}{2})+n^{2}\log n$, we have $\log_{b}a = 1$, so we can pick any $\varepsilon \in (0,1]$ (say for the sake of argument we pick $\varepsilon = 1$) and we have $f(n) \in \Omega(n^{1+\varepsilon}) = \Omega(n^{2})$.

Thus we can conclude $T(n) \in \Theta(n^{2}\log n)$.

In this case we don't need to worry too much about the regularity condition as $n^{2}\log n$ is well behaved - the condition is there to stop tricky things like the ones mentioned in the Wikipedia article, such as $f(n)=n\cdot(2-\cos n)$.